# Laravel Project downloading error Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel

[image]

How to solve this Error when downloading laravel project. I install Ubuntu 22.04 today

I tried but I am not ok

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the error is an image and not text.

Comment: Look up how to enable the `xml` and `dom` extensions in your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the xml extenstion of PHP.

```
apt-get install php8.1-xml
```

Comment: Same for the dom extension.